# Could I please have my privilege to edit without a peer review removed?

Tags: support, editing

I have hit the 2k-rep threshold recently, and hence my edits should now be automatically accepted without a peer review. However:

1. My English, though fluent, is very far from perfect. I can't edit a post written by a native speaker if I don't want to spoil it by a stupid mistake, even if I have something to add -- because my mistake will persist until someone fixes it. Sometimes I have even used edits to fix obvious mistakes and clarified in the edit summary that some more editing is needed, attracting attention of edit reviewers.
2. Sometimes I may just be wrong due to being a noob, and a peer review might fix my mistake before I mislead someone by wrong information.

Even though most of my edits were accepted, I just don't feel confident enough to put my edits in place without someone reviewing them. I would like my ability to edit without review revoked.

Comment: You could downvote and bounty some things to get yourself under 2k again.

Comment: @THiebert I thought about this, but didn't like that idea.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy I see you've done a bounty. Are you truly planning to stay under 2k, forever?

Comment: @markovchain Well, I am considering that, but in this case I just felt like doing a bounty for so huge effort. nitsua60 has dedicated a lot of time to answer a question, so I wanted to thank him.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is super unlikely to happen; there's nothing in the system for revoking specific privileges from specific individuals. You have this feature now and it's going to be sticking around.

Basic principle: **you shouldn't edit unless you're sure you're doing the right thing anyway.** The suggested edit review queues are a safety net against obvious badness or abuse of the system, but they *aren't* a peer-review service that ensures everything going through is also factually correct, or that the spelling/grammar is impeccable. People reviewing suggested edits may not know better than you about the post, and may take your word for it because you seem to know what you're doing.

> I just don't feel confident enough to put my edits in place without someone reviewing them.

That's fine. You're not. See the front page? Every time you edit something, it's going to get bumped to the top so that people can scrutinise what you've done:

[image: "modified 17 minutes ago by doppelgreener"]

The post's author will *also* scrutinise what you've done, because the author gets a notification about your edit:

[image: "answer edited"]

We can @-ping you about your edits if we feel the need to, and anyone including yourself can open meta questions about [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) for guidance (such as earlier today: [Paraphrasing in Quotation Blocks](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6861/1204)). If you're not sure, you can check with people in chat, or just leave comments suggesting changes for the author and let them decide if and how the edit should be done.

You're stepping over the precipice into a lot of new power and responsibility, and it can definitely be a bit scary — you can now do a lot, and you alone are solely responsible for your actions! I'm really happy you're conscientious of your possible weaknesses and where your edits can go wrong, but that doesn't mean you should stop editing altogether *nor* were the review queues necessarily going to stop that. Just be extra careful in those circumstances.

We've got your back.